# Switching a USB HDD on and off

Tags: power, usb, switching

I have a PC which I backup to an external USB3 HDD drive from time to time, I manually connect the drive whenever I "remember" to do the offline backup. I don't want to keep it connected all the time in hope that it won't wear-down fast also protect it from accidental modification.

However, I would like to automate this process as well and have this backup done frequently and I was searching to see if simply disconnecting USB V-BUS is enough and also safe to simulate disconnecting the USB and that it will not cause any issues. I have seen similar questions but couldn't find any that matches my concerns.

I am thinking about using a CMOS P-channel (with bypass caps before and after) to control the Vcc, but the D+, D- and GND will remain connected! 
The USB plug is designed so that VCC and GND will connect first before the data lines, in my solution that won't be the case and I don't know what that might lead to.

Will this be safe? or should I just look for USB3 switches instead.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/701588 but I personally would not do it without concrete proof from the USB specification side. Usually signal voltage applied without power voltage is not allowed *unless* device is explicitly designed to tolerate it (this is what standard must confirm).

Comment: If you are automatically attaching hard disks, it is no longer an offline backup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your HDD enclosure is designed correctly (which is likely, since it likely will be using a standard trusted bridge IC), removing VBUS should cause the drive to disconnect, and upon restoring VBUS the drive should get fresh enumeration. Without VBUS nothing should happen. At least there is no danger to try VBUS off and on.

I personally just turn off the entire 12V DC power with a switch.

I wouldn't advise to make "USB 3.0 switch", it is a failing proposition. It is doable, but would require to carefully build a PCB with impedance-controlled differential traces and good qualified USB 3.0 connectors with proper fan-out, it will take a good effort.

ADDITION: Correctly designed USB device must signal its connect event (start USB 3.0 termination detect or D+ pullup) only if VBUS is present, regardless if it is self- or bus-powered. The rule is **"no VBUS - no connect"**. In all cases. See Section 7.2.1 and 7.1.5, USB devices *"may not provide power to the pull-up resistor on D+/D- unless VBUS is present."* So this [old article](https://superuser.com/a/701588/620011) is correct.

Comment: I would like to add to that that bluntly disconnecting the USB connection is asking for trouble. It is advised to first unmount / remove / eject the drive before disconnecting. A much better idea would be to power down the USB drive via software. So leaving ot connected just in a standby state.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, unmounting and remounting is not an issue and will be handled easily by the backup script but I am concerned about the electrical issues that might happen with having some lines connected with no power (that is why i posted here in Electrical Engineering and not on Super User)

Comment: I won't go with the USB3 switch idea, since as you said will need more work than its worth. I am using a portable Seagate drive, do you think it is possible to find the datasheet for the USB-SATA bridge to see if it can tolerate being connected with no power? or they use propriety ICs?

Comment: @FahadAlduraibi, which "portable" drive? Does it have external power adapter, or it gets power from USB port?

Comment: @Ale..chenski, it uses the USB power [model: STDR2000202]

Comment: @FahadAlduraibi, if it gets power from USB port, then definitely it will shut itself down if you disconnect the power, and then come back. The only thing you need is to provide a really good "high-side" power switch, a simple P-MOS might be difficult to fit. The switch must must be really low Rdson, because these HDD mobile enclosure are usually very sensitive to supply's voltage level. I would highly recommend something like Infineon BTC500xx series of switches, excellent devices.